# Custom HttpStatusCode without Error Message (HttpActionResult)

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

I am currently working on Asp.net WebAPI2 Project. I am making a custom method for returning custom HttpStatusCode for error handling.

here's my code

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetError(int errCode) {
        int ErrCode = errCode * -1;
        ResourceManager ResourceManager = new ResourceManager("PIJ.API.OWIN.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        string ErrorMessage = ResourceManager.GetString("_" + ErrCode.ToString());

        return Content((HttpStatusCode)ErrCode, new HttpError(ErrorMessage));
    }
```

my current output is like this
[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwS4E.png)

my question is.
Is is possible to return only the HttpStatusCode, without the error Message ?

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi0Le.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should post the code instead of screenshots

Comment: @Prima, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code as **plain text** in the body of your question. Adding it as an image makes it very difficult for people to adapt your code to an answer, you can't copy-paste it, and it's hostile to those dependent on screen-readers

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.. Sorry this is my first time asking question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `StatusCodeResult` with required `HttpStatusCode`. This can be done using `StatusCode` method of `ApiController`

```
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to return a custom status code ? .. for example I want to return Error 600

Comment: yes, you can do this `StatusCode((HttpStatusCode)600);`